# Railsエンジンのmountが上手く行かず、uninitialized constant(NameError)がでてしまいます。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

以下のgemを導入したいと思っております。

https://github.com/fnando/coupons

READMEの手順どおり、
Gemfileに追加をした上で、

$ bundle install

config/routes.rbの編集

をしたのですが、

uninitialized constant Coupons::Engine (NameError)

というエラーがでます。

Railsエンジンの問題かと思い以下のようなサイトを元に調べているのですが、原因がわからず困っております。
http://railsguides.jp/engines.html

railsのコンソール上では確かに
Couponsのモジュールは読み込みされているのですが、
Coupons::Engineのモジュールはありませんでした。

こういう場合にどのような手順を踏んでいけば解決できるのかがわかないです。

github上のissueやpull requestなども探したのですが、解決方法はなく・・・。

宜しくお願いします。

=============2016/05/02 追記 =================

user3758624さんの回答の通り、

gem 'coupons', git: 'https://github.com/fnando/coupons.git'

とすると、上手くいきました。

しかし、その後に

http://localhost:3000/coupons

にアクセスした際に以下のエラーがでます。

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Coupons::Coupons#index

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: coupons: SELECT  "coupons".* FROM "coupons"  ORDER BY "coupons"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 51 OFFSET 0
```

原因はcouponのgemで使用するはずのcouponモデルが生成されてないためだと思います。

こちらで、couponモデルをつくるのではなく、gem側でモデルを作成するようなコードになっているようにみえるのですが、上手くいきません。

度々で申し訳ありませんが、再度ご知恵をお貸しいただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 1) `uninitialized constant Coupons::Engine (NameError)` が出るのは、いつでしょうか？`rails s` をした時でしょうか？  2) 同名のクラスを定義してい
たりしませんか？

Comment: uninitialized constant Coupons::Engine (NameError) が出るのは、rails sをした時です。また同名のクラスは定義しておりません。

Answer (score 2):

`gem 'coupons', git: 'https://github.com/fnando/coupons.git'`
にして bundle しなおしてください。

gem 'coupons' で落ちてくるコードの中身は、空でした.

```
require 'coupons/version'

module Coupons
  # Your code goes here...
end
```

Comment: ご回答有難う御座います。仰る方法で上手くいきました。しかし、別の箇所で再度エラーが発生してしまいました。質問本文最後に追記という形で加えました。もし宜しければ、再度お知恵をお貸しいただけないでしょうか。

Comment: @zyosh さん 
`bundle exec rake db:migrate` をしてください。

Comment: migrationはこちら側でしなくてはいけなかったんですね。（むしろ当たり前ですよね？）根深い問題なのかと思っておりましたが、私の凡ミスでした。ご丁寧に有難うございました。また一つ勉強になりました！